# Twitter Bootstrap inline input with dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, textinput

I'm trying to display a text input inline with a dropdown button.  I can't figure out how to do this though.  Here's the HTML I've tried (I've put all of it on a single line with no results):

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input type="text" placeholder="foo" class="input-mini">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a id="amount_type" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">10<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul id="amount_type_options" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="selected"><a href="#">10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">1000</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Try Bootstrap Combobox plugin: http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-combobox/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Current state: default implementation in docs

Currently there is a default implementation of input+dropdown combo in the documentation [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) (search for "Button dropdowns"). I leave the original solution for the record and for those who cannot use solution now included in the documentation.

### Original solution

Yes, it is possible. As a matter of fact, there is one example in [the Twitter Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html) (follow the link and search "*Examples*" for dropdown buttons):

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
        <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> User
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Ban</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="i"></i> Make admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If enclosed within text, it can look like this (with text on the button changed, nothing else):

[image: Twitter Bootstrap dropdown button within text]

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to achieve `<input>` with appended dropdown menu as in the dropdown buttons, then this is one of the solutions:

1. Add a `btn-group` class to the element that has `input-append` class,
2. Add elements with classes `dropdown-toggle` and `dropdown-menu` at the end of the element with class `input-append`,
3. Override style for element matching `.input-append .btn.dropdown-menu` so it does not have `float: left` (otherwise it will get into next line).

The resulting code may look like this:

```html
<div class="input-append btn-group">
    <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Ban</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="i"></i> Make admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with a little support from this style override:

```css
.input-append .btn.dropdown-toggle {
    float: none;
}
```

and give you the exact same result as this:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Updated the CSS selector (was `.dropdown-menu`, is `.dropdown-toggle`).

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually looking for an input field with a dropdown button appended on the end.  If you look at the Forms section of the link you provided and check out the "Append with button" example, you'll see what I mean.  Except in that example, it's a regular button and I'm trying to figure out how to use a dropdown instead.

Comment: @MishaM: It looks like you are trying to create your own dropdown implementation. May I ask why? This usually means you should use just a dropdown, probably with a little styling. Do you need something different than dropdown (`<select><option>option A</option><option>option B</option></select>`)?

Comment: The dropdown is a qualifier for the input.  The input contains the amount and the dropdown contains the units.  I can implement them separately, but I'm trying to present a better experience to the user.

Comment: @MishaM: See updated answer. It now contains something similar to _Append with button_ you referenced.

Comment: This is great. On my browser though, the dropdown is on the left.  See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/misham/v9fyf/2/   Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: @MishaM: See the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/v9fyf/4/ - I missed the selector and did not tell you about the need to remove any space between the input field and the dropdown button.

Answer (score 13):

As of Bootstrap 3.x, there's an example of this in the docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: he probably wanted a filter on a dropdown associated to the input

Answer (score 11):

Search for the "datalist" tag.

```
<input list="texto_pronto" name="input_normal">
<datalist id="texto_pronto">
    <option value="texto A">
    <option value="texto B">
</datalist>
```

Comment: By far this is the easiest option to use. No idea why this was downvoted! +1 buddy for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution is use  **display: inline**

```
Some text <div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> is here
```

a

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />Your text
<div class="dropdown" style="display: inline">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>is here
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the code for Bootstrap with input search dropdown.
I search a lot then i try its in javascript and html with bootstrap,

HTML Code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Language</label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button id="mydef" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="doOn(this);">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search" onkeyup="doOn(this);"></input>
            </div>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
         </button>
      <ul id="def" class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none;" >
            <li><a id="HTML" onclick="mydef(this);" >HTML</a></li>
            <li><a id="CSS" onclick="mydef(this);" >CSS</a></li>
            <li><a id="JavaScript" onclick="mydef(this);" >JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="def1" class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Javascript Code :

```
function doOn(obj)
     {

        if(obj.id=="mydef")
        {
            document.getElementById("def1").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("def").style.display="block";
        }
        if(obj.id=="search")
        {
            document.getElementById("def").style.display="none";

            document.getElementById("def1").innerHTML='<li><a id="Java" onclick="mydef(this);" >java</a></li><li><a id="oracle" onclick="mydef(this);" >Oracle</a></li>';

            document.getElementById("def1").style.display="block";
        }

    }
    function mydef(obj)
    {
        document.getElementById("search").value=obj.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("def1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("def").style.display="none";
    }
```

You can use jquery and json code also as per your requirement.

Output like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Daniel Farrell's Bootstrap Combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) does the job perfectly. Here's an example from his GitHub repository.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.combobox').combobox();
  
  // bonus: add a placeholder
  $('.combobox').attr('placeholder', 'For example, start typing "Pennsylvania"');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.8/css/bootstrap-combobox.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.8/js/bootstrap-combobox.min.js"></script>

<select class="combobox form-control">
  <option></option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
</select>
```

As an added bonus, I've included a placeholder in script since applying it to the markup does not hold.